# Cant access folder on server- Permission denied

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions, virtualhost, modx

I am running a vps with ubuntu 11.04. After a clean Modx install I've tried to access http://www.encepence.pl/manager and I've got a permission denied by my server. the thing is that I can easily access any other folder under that domain and modify this folder(manager) content via ftp.
I’ve tried modifying virtual host with that

```
<Directory /var/www/blackflow/data/www/encepence.pl/manager/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But it didn't work.

```
<Directory /var/www/blackflow/data/www/encepence.pl>
    Options -ExecCGI -Includes
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/blackflow/data:."
    php_admin_flag engine on
</Directory>

<VirtualHost 192.166.219.34:80 >
    ServerName encepence.pl
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/encepence.pl.access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/blackflow/data/www/encepence.pl

    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/encepence.pl.error.log
    ServerAdmin pomoc@blackflow.pl
    ServerAlias www.encepence.pl
    SuexecUserGroup blackflow blackflow
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/blackflow/data:."
    php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f pomoc@blackflow.pl"
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/blackflow/data/mod-tmp"
    php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/blackflow/data/mod-tmp"
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/blackflow/data/www/%0

</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas on what might have gone wrong?

Comment: What do you see in the logs (/var/www/httpd-logs/encepence.pl.error.log and /var/www/httpd-logs/encepence.pl.access.log) when you try to access it?

Comment: Permission denied: /usr/local/ispmgr/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions for one of the directories above that file (or the .htaccess file itself) most likely has improper permissions set to use it.

Check the permissions of '/usr/local/ispmgr', '/usr/local', and '/usr/' until you find which directory has the invalid permissions.  The web server needs at a minimum execute (+x) permissions to be able to read a file within that directory.

Try 'chmod a+x /usr/local/ispmgr /usr/local /usr' and 'chmod a+r /usr/local/ispmgr/.htaccess' if you aren't familiar with setting permissions to get started.

Comment: it's getting more and more interesting:/. When I chmod /usr/local/ispmgr  http://www.encepence.pl/manager redirects me to my ispmanager login page! As for the .htaccess file I couldn't find one so I've made a blank one. Now I get that error:
/usr/local/ispmgr/.htaccess: Invalid command '------WebKitFormBoundary5SydCNWPKSjdR0zF', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.